# What good are JUnit's @Ignore and @Disabled annotations?

Tags: junit

What is the advantage to adding the `@Disabled` or `@Ignore` annotations to JUnit tests, e.g.:

```
  @Test
  @Disabled
  void testSomething() { /* ... */ }
```

instead of just removing the `@Test` annotation?

```
  void testSomething() { /* ... */ }
```

Either way, the test should not be executed.

Comment: You can use them at class level instead of removing all test annotations if you just want to (temporarily) skip some tests for whatever reasons. Additionally they're counted as "skipped tests" in the reports, as opposed to being completely overlooked, so you have an idea about what's happening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The utility of these annotations is largely in documentation/reporting. When you run a JUnit suite, you get a report of the results. `@Ignored`/`@Disabled` tests will be marked as such (with optional comments) in that report.

This lets you track how many tests are being ignored/disabled. You can set policies around this (i.e. if a test is `@Ignored` for a month, just delete it) or make CI systems fail if too many tests are being `@Ignored`. You can make graphs showing trends of Passed/Failed/Skipped over time.

Really, it all comes down to how you want to track the evolution of your test suite, and wether you'd want to see a section of "skipped" tests, or the total number of tests going down when a test is temporarily broken/no longer useful.

Answer (score 5):

`@Disabled` or `@Ignore` annotations can be used to disable or ignore the test methods from the test suite.

`@Disabled` introduced in junit5. It accepts only one optional parameter, which indicates the reason this test is disabled. Example :

```
@Disabled("Do not run in a lower environment")
```

**Advantages of adding `@Disabled` or `@Ignore`:**

1. **Search-ability**: You can easily identify all `@Ignore` or `@Disabled` annotations in the source code, while unannotated or commented out tests are not so simple to find.
2. **Maintainable**: It is easy to maintain or modify it later. It is always good practice to use annotations.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, @Ignore is cleaner than commenting an entire block of test method .

Also, when you run your test suite, you would get a warning about some tests are ignored. You won’t get that if you comment it. That maybe someday you would want to enable it

Comment: PO did not talk about commenting out code. His last option was about removing the @Test annotation from the method so that it is not run as test.

Answer (score 0):

**Other advantages:**

- **Manual-only execution:** ensures a test is never run automatically while still allowing you to run it manually with no code change. My preferred approach for this, since it defaults to safe behaviour without requiring any configuration of test engine or test run.
- **Avoids warnings**: untagging can trigger "unused code"-warnings for tests that are in use, only manually
- **Modularity**: You can use it on an entire test class, whereas in JUnit 5 you would need to untag each test case individually